# fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Estoy trabajando Entity framework 7.3 y net core6.0. Después de ejecutar mi aplicación y hacer consultas a mi base de datos me permite hacer uno, dos o a veces hasta 3 consultas antes de tener este error. Luego tengo que cerrar la aplicación y volverla a abrir para seguir realizando la misma cantidad de consultas.

Hasta ahora he borrado la base de datos y las migraciones, pero con el resultado similar.

el error es el siguiete.

```
  fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (Size = 20)], 
  CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

  SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [Cliente] SET [Telefono] = @p0
  OUTPUT 1
  WHERE [Id_cliente] = @p1;
```

El segundo problema que tengo es que cuando intento modificar a mi tabla cliente. La sección de "referencia" es la única que no se modifica.

El codigo para generar la base de datos es el siguiente.

```
using cadeteria.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace cadeteria;

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Cadetes> Cadetes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Clientes> Clientes { get; set; }


public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    List<Cadetes> listCadete = new List<Cadetes>();
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc0"), Nombre = "Jaun Castellanos", Direccion = "Entre rios", Telefono = "231321231" });
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("0a9fa564-0604-4dfa-88df-3636fe395651"), Nombre = "Ana Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "231321231" });
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("0a9fa564-0604-4dfa-88df-3636fe395678"), Nombre = "Fer Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "654321" });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Cadetes>(Cadete =>
    {
        Cadete.ToTable("Cadete");
        Cadete.HasKey(p => p.Id_cadete);

        Cadete.Property(p => p.Nombre).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Cadete.Property(p => p.Direccion).IsRequired();
        Cadete.Property(p => p.Telefono).IsRequired();
        Cadete.Ignore(p => p.Listpedido);

        Cadete.HasData(listCadete);
    });

    List<Clientes> listaCliente = new List<Clientes>();
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc3"), Nombre = "Pancho Castellanos", Direccion = "Entre rios", Telefono = "5231234" });
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc1"), Nombre = "Lucio Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "8321156" });
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc5"), Nombre = "Val Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "975313" });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Clientes>(Clientes =>
    {
        Clientes.ToTable("Cliente");
        Clientes.HasKey(p => p.Id_cliente);

        Clientes.Property(p => p.Id_cliente).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Nombre).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Direccion).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Telefono).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Referencia).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(100);

        Clientes.HasData(listaCliente);
    });

}

}
```

Alguna idea que me puedan aclarar.
mi repositorio donde se encuentra este proyecto es el siguiente [Link](https://github.com/leandroVece/React-ASP.Net)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo cámbiale la versión del entity framework, también me paso lo mismo, estaba usando la v 7 y se la cambie por la 6.0.3 y me empezó a funcionar de maravilla, espero te sirva

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias me di cuenta de eso después de un tiempo, pero estoy muy agradecido con tu respuesta.